# How to always keep the sum of values of dynamically generated input boxes equal to a specific result in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, html

I am generating a set of dynamic input boxes i want to always keep the sum of the values equal to a specific result. So when I change any value of a input box the other values should change in a way to keep the sum unchanged. How shall I do that using `AngularJS`?

Below is my div

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in SecurityAllocationList track by $index">
    <input type="number" data-ng-model="item.InvestAmount" />
</div>
```

[image]I want to achieve this
[image: Here amount to be achieved is 9000]

Comment: use ng-change in each text box and change the other textbox values using ng-model.

Comment: Suppose I have to get 1000 as sum and 4 text boxes are generated. So 1st text box is populated with 1000 and rest three boxes have 0. Now in 2nd,3rd and 4th text boxes if I enter 50 each it should display 850,50,50,50 respectively in all the text boxes. How to achieve it?

Comment: From How To Ask (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."  You need to show us what you've tried or at the least show us your controller code with the model for your dynamically generated input boxes

Comment: How do you want to distribute the values ?

Comment: In the case of `6 inputs` and total `9000`, I edited `first` input box to 100, then  how should the remaining value to be distributed. After that I edit `fifth` text box what will be the behavior of `first` input box which I already changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Yow will need a function to calculate the amounts when one changes and possibly when the page loads, like this:

```
  $scope.recalc = function(item) {

    var itemCount = $scope.SecurityAllocationList.length;
    var denominator = itemCount;

    var numerator = $scope.totalAmt;
    if (item) {
      numerator = $scope.totalAmt - item.InvestAmount;
      denominator -= 1;
    }
   var remaining = numerator / denominator;
   angular.forEach($scope.SecurityAllocationList, function(inv) {
      if (inv !== item) {
       inv.InvestAmount = remaining;
     }
    });
  };
```

This will be called from the ng-change directive on your input element like this:

```
<input type="number" data-ng-model="item.InvestAmount" ng-change="recalc(item)"/>
```

I've created a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Odu7d6VsSHHgADk8pl2F?p=preview) to illustrate.

Comment: plunker output is telling Unable to connect to any application instances.

Comment: Yes, I think plunker is having some server issues but you should be able to see the code

Comment: I just noticed that you can click the 'Launch the preview in a separate window' icon in the upper right of the plunker preview pane, you can see it working